# Example of a subalgebra $\mathfrak{h}$ of a semisimple algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ s.t. $\mathfrak{h}$ is not semisimple.

Tags: solution-verification, lie-algebras

Nilpotent and solvable Lie algebras have the property that their subalgebras are also nilpotent and solvable correspondingly. That is not true for semisimple algebras.

*Does this example works?*

Take $\mathfrak{g}=sl_n(\mathbb{C})$ and $\mathfrak{h}=sl_n(\mathbb{C})\cap UT_n(\mathbb{C})$ where $UT_n(\mathbb{C})$ is an algebra of upper triangular matrices. We can see that $\mathfrak{h}$ is solvable since $\mathfrak{h}$ consists of upper triangular matrices.

Comment: Just take $\mathfrak{h}$ as the Cartan subalgebra of a semisimple Lie algebra see Torsten's answer. It is abelian and nonzero hence not semisimple. Write it down for $\mathfrak{sl}_n(\Bbb C)$. This is useful anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, your example works. But there are many, many more examples. E.g. just notice that for any non-zero element $x$ of any Lie algebra $\mathfrak g$ (over any field $k$), the one-dimensional subspace spanned by $x$, $\mathfrak h := k\cdot x$, is a Lie subalgebra of $\mathfrak g$ (since $[x,x]=0 \in k\cdot x$). Being abelian and non-zero, it is of course not semisimple.

Another example: In the structure theory of semisimple Lie algebras, the *Cartan subalgebras* play an important role. Again, they are abelian subalgebras, hence not semisimple. Likewise, your example is a special case of a *Borel subalgebra*, which is a maximal solvable subalgebra, also important in the structure theory and also not semisimple. But as said, there are many more.